# Why doesnt' probe execute?

Tags: functional-programming, prolog

Why does Probe not execute? This is not the whole program, but should be sufficient code to find an answer. Yes, I already scoured Stack Overflow for an answer but there is not much help for Prolog. It is part of a minesweeper game.

```
play :-    
    play(0).

play(M) :-
   N is M + 1,
   Suf <- N,
   display_board(visible), nl,
   format("Your ~d~a move~n", [N,Suf]),
   retrieve('Coordinates? ', [A,B]),
   format("DEBUG: probing at coordinates [~d,~d]~n", [A, B]),
   !, probe(A,B),
   play(N).


probe(X, Y) :-
   write("enter probe"),
   located_at(Who, X, Y, C),
   C = 'b',
   write('should probe '),
   write('at ['),
   write(X), write(','), write(Y), write(']'), nl.
  :- style_check(+singleton).
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us step back and first try to find out: Why does the program not even **compile**?

When consulting the program you posted, I get:

> ```
> ERROR: file.pl:6:6: Syntax error: Operator expected
> ```

This is the line that says:

> ```
>    Suf <- N
> ```

That's not valid Prolog syntax.

Therefore, I suggest to fix this first.

In fact, I further get:

> ```
> Warning: file.pl:14: Singleton variables: [Who]
> ```

That's also not a good sign. But the `ERROR` is more severe, preventing compilation of the whole clause.

Comment: It doesn't compile because this is not the entire file. Would you like me to include the complete file?

Comment: What I would like most is a minimal example that shows precisely the issue you want to solve! That is, ideally, you should remove everything from the file that is not really relevant to the issue, and include those parts that clearly exhibit it. I suggest you edit the answer to show all relevant parts of the file, and exclude the rest.